# Magento 2 remove subtotal from Invoice PDF

Tags: magento2, invoice-pdf

I've been trying to remove subtotal from the invoice pdf.

I have override **vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/pdf.xml** from my custom module but didn't work. I have just commented on the subtoal. but it not working.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it in a perfect and standard way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best approach is to overwrite the `view/frontend/layout/sales_order_printinvoice.xml` layout file in your custom theme and change the line:

```xml
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Invoice\Totals" name="invoice_totals" template="Magento_Sales::order/totals.phtml" cacheable="false">
```

so that it uses a custom block class, then create this custom block class in your module and make it inherit the `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Invoice\Totals` class, then override the `_initTotals()` method like this:

```php
protected function _initTotals()
{
    parent::_initTotals();
    $this->removeTotal('subtotal');
    return $this;
}
```

You probably already saw that the totals used in invoice pdf are used in other invoice related functionalities and that they are registered programmatically on the PHP side. My suggestion described above is to leave the other functionalities untouched while adding your customization only in the area of interest (so no preference, plugin or manual validations in the phtmls).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @diana-botean It's working.

Comment: glad I could help :) you are most welcome!